# On ordinary differential equations (ODE) and optimization, in Python

Tags: python, optimization, ode

I want to solve this kind of problem:

```
dy/dt = 0.01*y*(1-y), find t when y = 0.8 (0<t<3000)
```

I've tried the ode function in Python, but it can only calculate y when t is given.

So are there any simple ways to solve this problem in Python?

---

PS: This function is just a simple example. My real problem is so complex that can't be solve analytically. So I want to know how to solve it numerically. And I think this problem is more like an optimization problem:

```
Objective function y(t) = 0.8, Subject to dy/dt = 0.01*y*(1-y), and 0<t<3000
```

---

PPS: My real problem is:

```
objective function: F(t) = 0.85, 
subject to: F(t) = sqrt(x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2), 
            x''(t) = (1/F(t)-1)*250*x(t), 
            y''(t) = (1/F(t)-1)*250*y(t), 
            z''(t) = (1/F(t)-1)*250*z(t)-10, 
            x(0) = 0, y(0) = 0, z(0) = 0.7, 
            x'(0) = 0.1, y'(0) = 1.5, z'(0) = 0, 
            0<t<5
```

Comment: aint this possible analytically? (swap dt to the right, integrate both, and you get an equation out of which you can get y(t) ?)

Comment: @usethedeathstar : Yes. But it's just a simple example. My real function is quite complex (no way to solve in analytical method). So I want to know how to solve this numerically in Python.

Comment: can you give the real equation?

Comment: @usethedeathstar Real one is: `objective function F(t) = 0.85, subject to F(t) = sqrt(x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2), x''(t) = (1/F(t)-1)*250*x(t), y''(t) = (1/F(t)-1)*250*y(t), z''(t) = (1/F(t)-1)*250*z(t)-10, x(0) = 0, y(0) = 0, z(0) = 0.7, x'(0) = 0.1, y'(0) = 1.5, z'(0) = 0, 0<t<5`

Comment: can you put it in the post itself instead of in comment? so others who read the post dont have to read all comments too, before replying?

Comment: can you analytically simplify it by going to spherical coords?

Comment: and can you give some more (physical) explanation behind the problem? (seems like a fairly classical second bachelor maths exercise?)

Comment: Maybe, I'll take a shot at it. I'm trying to build a 3D spring-mass model in Python. These are dynamic equations of the model. `[x y z]` is the coordinate of mass. `F(t)` is the length of spring.

Comment: i think on http://math.stackexchange.com they will be able to help you better on how to solve it (wether analytically or a specific numerical solving method that should work great for this type of problem), and once there you found the right method to solve it, ask the question here on how to implement the suggested method they gave in python? Did you try with maple or mathematica or so to see if its analytically possible?

Comment: Maybe a naive question, but why don`t you use the ode integrator as function call for the objective function used by an optimization routine ?

Answer (score 2):

This differential equation can be solved analytically quite easily:

dy/dt = 0.01 * y * (1-y)

rearrange to gather y and t terms on opposite sides

100 dt = 1/(y * (1-y)) dy

The lhs integrates trivially to 100 * t, rhs is slightly more complicated. We can always write a product of two quotients as a sum of the two quotients * some constants:

1/(y * (1-y)) = A/y + B/(1-y)

The values for A and B can be worked out by putting the rhs on the same denominator and comparing constant and first order y terms on both sides. In this case it is simple, A=B=1. Thus we have to integrate

1/y + 1/(1-y) dy

The first term integrates to ln(y), the second term can be integrated with a change of variables u = 1-y to -ln(1-y). Our integrated equation therefor looks like:

100 * t + C = ln(y) - ln(1-y)

not forgetting the constant of integration (it is convenient to write it on the lhs here). We can combine the two logarithm terms:

100 * t + C = ln( y / (1-y) )

In order to solve t for an exact value of y, we first need to work out the value of C. We do this using the initial conditions. It is clear that if y starts at 1, dy/dt = 0 and the value of y never changes. Thus plug in the values for y and t at the beginning

100 * 0 + C = ln( y(0) / (1 - y(0) )

This will give a value for C (assuming y is not 0 or 1) and then use y=0.8 to get a value for t. Note that because of the logarithm and the factor 100 multiplying t y will reach 0.8 within a relatively short range of t values, unless the initial value of y is incredibly small. It is of course also straightforward to rearrange the equation above to express y in terms of t, then you can plot the function as well.

**Edit: Numerical integration**

For a more complexed ODE which cannot be solved analytically, you will have to try numerically. Initially we only know the value of the function at zero time y(0) (we have to know at least that in order to uniquely define the trajectory of the function), and how to evaluate the gradient. The idea of numerical integration is that we can use our knowledge of the gradient (which tells us how the function is changing) to work out what the value of the function will be in the vicinity of our starting point. The simplest way to do this is Euler integration:

y(dt) = y(0) + dy/dt * dt

Euler integration assumes that the gradient is constant between t=0 and t=dt. Once y(dt) is known, the gradient can be calculated there also and in turn used to calculate y(2 * dt) and so on, gradually building up the complete trajectory of the function. If you are looking for a particular target value, just wait until the trajectory goes past that value, then interpolate between the last two positions to get the precise t.

The problem with Euler integration (and with all other numerical integration methods) is that its results are only accurate when its assumptions are valid. Because the gradient is not constant between pairs of time points, a certain amount of error will arise for each integration step, which over time will build up until the answer is completely inaccurate. In order to improve the quality of the integration, it is necessary to use more sophisticated approximations to the gradient. Check out for example the Runge-Kutta methods, which are a family of integrators which remove progressive orders of error term at the cost of increased computation time. If your function is differentiable, knowing the second or even third derivatives can also be used to reduce the integration error.

Fortunately of course, somebody else has done the hard work here, and you don't have to worry too much about solving problems like numerical stability or have an in depth understanding of all the details (although understanding roughly what is going on helps a lot). Check out http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html#scipy.integrate.ode for an example of an integrator class which you should be able to use straightaway. For instance

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
def deriv(t, y):
    return 0.01 * y * (1 - y)
my_integrator = ode(deriv)
my_integrator.set_initial_value(0.5)
t = 0.1  # start with a small value of time
while t < 3000:
    y = my_integrator.integrate(t)
    if y > 0.8:
        print "y(%f) = %f" % (t, y)
        break
    t += 0.1
```

This code will print out the first t value when y passes 0.8 (or nothing if it never reaches 0.8). If you want a more accurate value of t, keep the y of the previous t as well and interpolate between them.

Comment: Thank you. But `dy/dt = 0.01*y*(1-y)` is just a simple example. My real function is very complex (can't be solved analytically). I want to know how to solve this kind of problem numerically in Python. It seems more like a optimization problem -- `objective function y(t) = 0.8, subject to dy/dt = 0.01*y*(1-y) and 0<t<3000`. Do you have any idea how to deal with it in Python?

Comment: @gpzhao, an optimisation problem requires you to know y(t) explicitly, not just dy/dt. I have edited my answer to include a solution in Python, hope it helps

Comment: I've tried this and I want to know whether there's a better way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Krastanov`s answer:

Aside of PyDSTool there are other packages, like [Pysundials](http://pysundials.sourceforge.net/) and [Assimulo](http://www.jmodelica.org/assimulo) which provide bindings to the solver [IDA](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/ida_guide.pdf) from Sundials. This solver has root finding capabilites.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scipy.integrate.odeint` to handle your integration, and analyse the results afterward.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

ts = np.arange(0,3000,1)   # time series - start, stop, step

def rhs(y,t):
    return 0.01*y*(1-y)

y0 = np.array([1])    # initial value

ys = odeint(rhs,y0,ts)
```

Then analyse the numpy array `ys` to find your answer (dimensions of array `ts` matches `ys`).  (This may not work first time because I am constructing from memory).

This might involve using the `scipy interpolate` function for the `ys` array, such that you get a result at time `t`.

EDIT: I see that you wish to solve a spring in 3D.  This should be fine with the above method; `Odeint` on the `scipy` website has examples for systems such as coupled springs that can be solved for, and these could be extended.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this. Although it's possible to find the answer, I think it's not the best way (). Actually, the problem seems more like an optimization problem--`objection function: y(t) = 0.8, subject to dy/dt = 0.01*y(1-y) and 0<t<3000`. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm confused - your original question was "...are there any simple ways to solve this problem in Python?", which the above does.



Is this a mathematics problem?

Comment: No. The method you posted works, but may consume too much time if the function is quite complex (see my question PPS section) because of fixed step size. I want to know whether there are any built-in functions in Python could solve this problem directly. If there are, I think may be they're packed in optimization modules/packages.

Comment: Odeint uses a very optimized integration routine that doesn't step at a fixed size.  It will solve very complex functions much quicker than Euler/RK4 for example - it analyses the precomputed solutions and predicts the future ones, testing them, and re-calculating them if it cannot predict.  I would be surprised if it used up a lot of time for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a ODE integrator with root finding capabilities. They exist and the low-level code for such integrators is supplied with scipy, but they have not yet been wrapped in python bindings.

For more information see this mailing list post that provides a few alternatives: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-March/024890.html

You can use the following example implementation which uses backtracking (hence it is not optimal as it is a bolt-on addition to an integrator that does not have root finding on its own): https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4904/files